# Convert string in iso date format to milliseconds. Iso date format includes ("yyyy-MM-dd") and doesn't have timezone

Tags: java, date, time

Struggling to convert string in iso date format to milliseconds. I know there are similar questions to this, but I couldn't find one that included "yyyy-MM-dd" and didn't have timezone.

Short snippet of code for reference.

```
  class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
    String dateformat = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE.format(today);
    System.out.println(dateformat);  }
  }
```

Comment: `System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis());`

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

You asked:

> Convert string in iso date format to milliseconds. Iso date format includes (“yyyy-MM-dd”) and doesn't have timezone

```
OffsetDateTime                         // Represent a moment as a date, a time, and an offset.
.of(                                   // Factory method to instantiate a `OffsetDateTime` from a date, a time, and an offset.
    LocalDate.parse( "2021-01-23" ) ,  // Parse your input text.
    LocalTime.MIN ,                    // Constant for 00:00.
    ZoneOffset.UTC                     // Constant representing an offset-from-UTC of zero hours-minutes-seconds.
)                                      // Returns an `OffsetDateTime` object.
.toInstant()                           // Returns an `Instant` object.
.toEpochMilli()                        // Returns a `long` representing a count of milliseconds since 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z.
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/YuGJvD).

> 1611360000000

## Details

You said:

> string in iso date format

```
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.of( 2021 , Month.JANUARY , 23 ) ;
String output = localDate.toString() ;  // Uses ISO 8601 format by default.
```

> output: 2021-01-23

You said:

> convert string … milliseconds

Parse string as `LocalDate`.

```
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse( "2021-01-23" ) ;
```

For milliseconds since the [epoch reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(computing)) of first moment of 1970 in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time), we need a time of day. For time-of-day, use [`LocalTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalTime.html) class with its constant [`LocalTime.MIN`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html#MIN).

```
LocalTime localTime = LocalTime.MIN ;
```

Combine with [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) as the offset to get a [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) object, which represents a moment, a point on the timeline.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.of( localDate , localTime , ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;
```

Extract an [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html) from the `OffsetDateTime`.

```
Instant instant = odt.toInstant() ;
```

Interrogate the `Instant` for a count of milliseconds from epoch reference 1970-01-01T00:00Z.

```
long millisecondsSinceEpoch = instant.toEpochMilli() ;
```

---

[image: Table of all date-time types in Java, both modern and legacy]

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes. Hibernate 5 & JPA 2.2 support *java.time*.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).